# Typescript generic types for function that is updating nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, redux-toolkit

I'm building a generic function that will allow to update nested object properties (ideally based on inferred type - but this is nice to have rather than requirement).

On the top of that please keep in mind - I am not a Typescript expert so I would be glad for pointing out any mistakes.

So here is the example state + types for it:

```
type DataType = {
  knownKeyName1: {
    knownNestedKeyName1: string
    knownNestedKeyName2: string
    knownNestedKeyName3: string
    knownNestedKeyName4: string
  }
  knownKeyName2: {
    knownNestedKeyName1: string
    knownNestedKeyName2: string
    knownNestedKeyName3: string
  }
}

type SomeState = {
  data: DataType
}

const someState: SomeState = {
  data: {
    knownKeyName1: {
      knownNestedKeyName1: 'value',
      knownNestedKeyName2: 'value',
      knownNestedKeyName3: 'value',
      knownNestedKeyName4: 'value'
    },
    knownKeyName2: {
      knownNestedKeyName1: 'value',
      knownNestedKeyName2: 'value',
      knownNestedKeyName3: 'value'
    }
  }
}
```

And below is the function that I've already tried to build with Typescript's generics:

```
const setStateValue = <
  State extends { data: unknown }, // I want this to infer type from `someState` variable whenever I pass it to this function
  Prop extends [keyof State['data']],
  VarName extends keyof State['data'][Prop] // Type 'Prop' cannot be used to index type 'State["data"]'.ts(2536)
>(
  state: State,
  prop: Prop,
  varName: VarName,
  newValue: string
): void => {
  state.data[prop][varName] = newValue

  // Example usage should results with:
  // state.data[knownKeyName1][knownNestedKeyName3] = 'someNewValue'
}
```

JavaScript equivalent:

```
 const setStateValue = (state, prop, varName, newValue) => {
    state.data[prop][varName] = newValue // Object property reassignment is done on purpose because we want to update the state in reducer with `immer`
 }
```

Any ideas? Additionally, if that's not possible then it would be nice to at least have something like this:

```
const setStateValue = <
  State extends { data: DataType },
  Prop extends keyof DataType,
  VarName extends keyof DataType[Prop]
>(
  state: State,
  prop: Prop,
  varName: VarName,
  newValue: string
): void => {
  state.data[prop][varName] = newValue // but then this error pops out: 
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'DataType[Prop][VarName]'.ts(2322)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S Adding `#redux-toolkit` tag to give some usage context, as I want to use this `setStateValue` function inside generic reducer (so the state can be mutated with immer).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJqLrm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to show a use case where this fails.

Comment: @jcalz Here's [an alternative](https://tsplay.dev/WkGBJW) I derived from your suggestion. Not sure if it is an improvement, but it validates the keys based on the state type, instead of the other way around. It seemed more intuitive to me.

Comment: It depends on whether there's a requirement that `newValue` be of type `string`.  Maybe OP will clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. there is no requirements for `newValue` - it will be `string` type always and it's not so important in my problem. I've created [this playground](shorturl.at/hyzJ0 ) to highlight the problem I am facing - maybe it will be a bit more clear. @JJWesterkamp

Comment: The link I've provided seems to not work anymore, here is the [correct one](https://tsplay.dev/WzOY4w)